# vim: insert increase numbers on the specified column？

Tags: vim, editor, vi

I want to insert increase numbers on the specified column, such as the 8th column, but :r!seq 10 insert on 1st column.
I try

```
:set ve=all

8|<C-V>9jA0<ESC>gvlg<C-A>
```

but that's too clumsy.

So，can i use :r!seq 10 on the 8th column if not use visincr plugin? Just like Alt funtcion of notepad++.

Comment: maybe try asking [VI](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: do you need to create those lines? or the lines exist already?

Answer (score 0):

Don't see what's wrong with `g<C-A>`, but as an example of alternative solution:

```
:call setreg('', system('seq 10'), 'b2')
```

Then move cursor where you want and press `P`

With a bit of effort you can develop it into general purpose command/function/mapping by adding support to interactive `input()`, error checking, auto-computing block width, etc.